# Swift: Misaligned Large Titles when Rotating From Landscape

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

I have a weird issue with the large title, that the title misaligned when I rotate the device from landscape to portrait. You may see the gif as attached:

[image]

I'm not too sure if its due to the custom BarButtonItem, but after doing a scroll, the title readjusts itself back to the original position.

My code as such:

```
lazy var profileImageButton: UIButton = {
    let b = UIButton(type: .system)
    b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openSideMenu), for: .touchUpInside)
    b.setImage(UIImage(named: "testImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
    b.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    b.imageView?.clipsToBounds = true
    b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return b
}()

var compactConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
var regularConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
var heightContraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupUI()       
}

func setupUI() {        
    navigationItem.title = "Overview"
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: profileImageButton)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

    setupProfileImageButtonConstraints()

}

func setupProfileImageButtonConstraints() {
    heightContraint = profileImageButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 36)
    heightContraint.priority = UILayoutPriority(999)

    compactConstraints = [
        profileImageButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20),
        profileImageButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20)]

    regularConstraints = [
        profileImageButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 36),
        heightContraint
    ]

}

override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
    if traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .compact {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(regularConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(compactConstraints)
        profileImageButton.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    } else if traitCollection.verticalSizeClass == .regular {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(compactConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(regularConstraints)
        profileImageButton.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = 18
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can avoid that misalignment?

EDIT:

Attempted the following code inside my `tabBarController` as shared:

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    if let viewController = self.viewControllers?[self.selectedIndex] {
        return viewController.shouldAutorotate
    }
    return super.shouldAutorotate
}

override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if let viewController = self.viewControllers?[self.selectedIndex] {
        return viewController.supportedInterfaceOrientations
    }
    return super.supportedInterfaceOrientations
}

override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation {
    if let viewController = self.viewControllers?[self.selectedIndex] {
        return viewController.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
    }
    return super.preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
}
```

The results so far:

[image]

As you can see, the rotation rotates back as a `regularTitle`. Possible to rotate back as a `largeTitle`?

Comment: this might help https://theswiftdev.com/2017/10/31/ios-auto-layout-tutorial-programmatically/

Comment: @Flexicoder thanks for the resource. It kinda addresses the problem in a way that it masks it. Now after rotating back from landscape, the `navigationBar` is rotated back as a "regularTitle". I would very much prefer rotation back as a largeTitle. Any clues how I can acheive it? See edit